# How to add a macro command to all files that exist in solution or project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a existing project that I need to add a small macro command to many files of it how I can do it for project or solution file?
for example 
double_code(x) x; x;

Answer (score 0):

Just create a header file, define your macro inside of the header and include the header in all the files where you need the macro defined by the header.

It's just like you would share the declaration of a class or function.

Don't forget header guards.

Comment: thanks but I want do it in central place to do it only.

Comment: That's not how it works. Each source file needs it's includes. You can include only one file to each source, and in this included file, you include all other headers you need, but without including the source file just knows nothing, jon snow.